# Java - Misunderstand ceil and floor methods

Tags: java, math, theory, floor, ceil

floor:

> Returns the largest (closest to positive infinity) double value that is less than or equal to the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer. ...

ceil:

> Returns the smallest (closest to negative infinity) double value that is greater than or equal to the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer. ...

Source: [Docs Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

About **floor**: If I type `System.out.print(Math.floor(2.1));` returns `2.0` . Other example: `System.out.print(Math.floor(2.8));` returns `2.0` . I am going to argue this description with the example: if `floor(2.1)` was the largest (closest to positive infinity) as a result would be `3.0` not `2.0`, because `2.0` is closest to negative infinity I think. So if I change the description about floor:

> Returns the smallest (closest to negative infinity) double value that is less than or equal to the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer. ...

It makes sense for me, I would understand that `floor(2.1)` returns `2.0`

When I read "closest to positive infinity" and "closest to negative infinity" I think in the number line:

[image: The number line]

Source: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-negative-infinity)

EDIT: What I am asking is: the description broke my mind. My logic says (about **floor** for example): First, Ok when I listen floor I think in the smallest not in the largest. Second, if I returns the largest, that is greater not less than to the argument. The same happens with **ceil**

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: With your "new and improved" description of `floor()`, why would `floor(2.1)` return `2.0`? After all, `1.0`, `0.0`, `-1.0`, ... are all closer to negative infinity and all smaller than `2.0`.

Comment: Under your new definition, `floor` always returns the smallest possible `double`.

Comment: Re your edit: The current descriptions for `floor()` and `ceil()` make perfect sense if you think of them as describing [constrained optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_optimization) problems (specifically, [integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) problems). For example, `floor(a)` solves the constrained optimization problem of maximizing f(x) = x subject to the constraints that x is an integer and x <= a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Returns the largest (closest to positive infinity) double value that is less than or equal to the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer

The key is in the phrase **that is less than or equal to the argument**.

So 2.0 is the largest double value **that is less than or equal to** 2.1 that is also equal to an integer value.

Ditto for ceil: the description mentions the smallest value that is larger or equal to the input value...

So, the original descriptions are in fact correct.

Comment: I understand the key in that phrase. But if the description would say: "Returns the smallest (closest to negative infinity) double value", I would understand the entire description, because: `floor(2.8)` returns `2.0`

Comment: @Jason Just quibbling here, but "largest" suggests greatest magnitude. That's OK for positive numbers, but for negative it would return negative infinity. I think it would be clearer to say "greatest" instead of "largest". YMMV.

Comment: I guess that's why they clarified with `largest (closest to positive infinity)`.

Comment: Ahhh, I think that I understood the description. I was trying to understand: on one side "largest" and on the other side "that is less than or equal to the argument" separately, so that broke my mind. I am going to explain it in ELI5, so in the example: `floor(2.8)` is like to say: "ehh the maximum is 2.8 so find the largest in the range 2.8 to below."